# How can I get data from a loop generated multiple fields codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Please look at the picture

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rtfhi.png)

### What I want:

I want to post all the fields data to a specific controller when pressed in confirm order. And then want to add these to database.

### What problem I am facing:

I can't get the data from all fields. As it's a loop genereated fields. I placed the id's of each medicine in for each fields. But how can I post these all to a controller function and from the controller function i can receive those data and put into database?

I get the table from another php file. And the buttons are in another php file. so the confirm button and the table and fields are not from same php page.

here is the code:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span8">
        <div class="widget">
            <div class="widget-header">
                <div class="title">
                    <span class="fs1" aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xe14a;"></span> Short Quantity List from current stock....
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="widget-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal no-margin" action="<?php echo site_url('order/queue')?>" method="post">
                    <table class="table table-bordered" id="myTableDot">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <?php if($flag == "noprint") { ?>
                                <th class="center-align-text" style="width:9%; border: 1px solid #000;"><input id="select-all" type="checkbox" /></th>
                                <?php } ?>
                                <th style="width:17%; border: 1px solid #000;">Supplier</th>
                                <th style="width:15%; border: 1px solid #000;">Name</th>
                                <th class="hidden-phone center-align-text" style="width: 8%; border: 1px solid #000;">Order</th>
                                <th class="hidden-phone center-align-text" style="width: 7%; border: 1px solid #000;">Min Qty</th>
                                <th class="hidden-phone center-align-text" style="width: 8%; border: 1px solid #000;">Box Qty</th>
                                <th class="hidden-phone center-align-text" style="width: 8%; border: 1px solid #000;">In Stock</th>

                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="shortqtytable"> <?php } ?>

                            <?php //if($flag == "noprint") { ?>
<!--                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="8"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-mini btn-success pull-right">Add to Order</button></td>
                            </tr>-->
                            <?php //} ?>

                            <?php if($meds != FALSE){foreach ($meds->result() as $med) { { ?>



                            <tr>
                                <?php //if($flag == "noprint") { ?>
<!--                                <td style="width:5%;text-align:center;border: 1px solid #000;"><input type="checkbox" name="mid[]" value="<?php //echo $med->id; ?>" /></td>-->
                                <?php //} ?>
                                <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000; border-left: 1px solid #000;"><?php echo $med->Supplier; ?></td>
                                <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000; border-left: 1px solid #000;"><?php echo $med->name; ?></td>
                                 <td style="text-align: center; border-top: 1px solid #000; border-left: 1px solid #000; border-right: 1px solid #000;">
                                    <b>
                                    <form class="form-horizontal no-margin" action="<?php echo site_url('medicine/add_order'); ?>" method="post" id="raiseForm">



                                    <!-- <input type="text" name="stockqty" value="<?php //echo $med->name; ?>"></b> -->
                                    <input type="number" name="<?php echo $med->name; ?>"></b>
                                    <!-- <input type="hidden" name="trigger" value="addstock" /> -->
                                    <input type="hidden" name="name2" value="<?php echo $med->name; ?>"/>



                                    </form>

                                </td>

                                <td style="text-align: center; border-top: 1px solid #000; border-left: 1px solid #000;"><?php echo $med->minqty; ?></td>
                                <td style="text-align: center; border-top: 1px solid #000; border-left: 1px solid #000;"><?php echo $med->boxqty; ?></td>
                                <td style="text-align: center; border-top: 1px solid #000; border-left: 1px solid #000; border-right: 1px solid #000;"><b><?php echo $med->m_stok; ?></b></td>


                                <?php //if($flag == "noprint") { ?>
<!--                                <td class="center-align-text" style="border: 1px solid #000;">
                                    <div class="label label-important">Short</div>
                                </td>-->
                                <?php //} ?>
                            </tr>
                            <?php } } } ?>
                        <?php if($flag == "print") { ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="rebounce" value="medicine/shortqty" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you start a new form for each input? Have one form before the foreach and make the number variable name `name[]` then you will recieve an array of all the names to process. Also in this code I don&#39;t see where you are populating the IDs or values as you said you were doing (I should note that only the name of an input is used when posting).

Comment: Please post full code for the form. It doesn't look like the same code that generated the table...

Comment: Can you please give me some example code?

Comment: Post full code for the form as an *edit* to the question

Comment: added the full code

Comment: please help me there

Comment: Fix the formatting I cant read it properly and you aren't showing the form anymore. Show everything from the form delcaration to the foreach.. just show the whole table..

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dQRib9ETo80evvpk4kYi-7Q4KJbupAvu

Comment: please check the two pages code

Comment: Please post the desired table look description in a text form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies in the fact that every iteration of foreach you have a new `<form>` which means if you submit the form issues will occur and you won't get all of the fields. You already have a `<form>` wrapper that is the right place (I'm not privy to what it does), but you can just submit using that as it will encompass all the inputs you need.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span8">
        <div class="widget">
            <div class="widget-header">
                <div class="title">
                    <span class="fs1" aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xe14a;"></span> Short Quantity List from current stock....
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="widget-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal no-margin" action="<?php echo site_url('some_controller/process') ?>" method="post">
                    <table class="table table-bordered" id="myTableDot">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="center-align-text" style="width:9%; border: 1px solid #000;"><input id="select-all" type="checkbox" /></th>
                                <th style="width:17%; border: 1px solid #000;">Supplier</th>
                                <th style="width:15%; border: 1px solid #000;">Name</th>
                                <th class="hidden-phone center-align-text" style="width: 8%; border: 1px solid #000;">Order</th>
                                <th class="hidden-phone center-align-text" style="width: 7%; border: 1px solid #000;">Min Qty</th>
                                <th class="hidden-phone center-align-text" style="width: 8%; border: 1px solid #000;">Box Qty</th>
                                <th class="hidden-phone center-align-text" style="width: 8%; border: 1px solid #000;">In Stock</th>

                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="shortqtytable">
                            <?php foreach ($meds->result() as $med) { ?>    
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000; border-left: 1px solid #000;"><?php echo $med->Supplier; ?></td>
                                    <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000; border-left: 1px solid #000;"><?php echo $med->name; ?></td>
                                    <td style="text-align: center; border-top: 1px solid #000; border-left: 1px solid #000; border-right: 1px solid #000;">
                                        <input type="number" name="<?php echo $med->name; ?>"></b>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="name2" value="<?php echo $med->name; ?>"/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="text-align: center; border-top: 1px solid #000; border-left: 1px solid #000;"><?php echo $med->minqty; ?></td>
                                    <td style="text-align: center; border-top: 1px solid #000; border-left: 1px solid #000;"><?php echo $med->boxqty; ?></td>
                                    <td style="text-align: center; border-top: 1px solid #000; border-left: 1px solid #000; border-right: 1px solid #000;"><b><?php echo $med->m_stok; ?></b></td>
                                </tr>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="rebounce" value="medicine/shortqty" />
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit form">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
<?php 

class Some_controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function process() {
        print_r($_POST);
    }

}

?>
```

You also needed a submit input which I added before the `</form>` tag.

You could probably also use the `$_POST` array directly as the array keys will  be the name of the field, and the value being the order amount.

Comment: ( ! ) Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 130968 bytes) in C:\wamp64\www\capsol\application\controllers\dompdf\include\style.cls.php on line 353

Comment: Wherever that error is coming from it's unrelated to the code I posted as you can even see by the debug.

Comment: Yes, I know this is not related. Can you please give me a hint at least?

Comment: Did the above code resolve your question? If you have another question you should start another one. Comments arent for unrelated sub questions.

Comment: As a side note if it was easy I would have just said this is what it is. But mem exhausted can mean so many things ...